# How do I create a Mongo Collection in Node with a variable name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

To insert in node into a Mongo Collection the command is

```
db.collection.insertOne({.........});
```

and currently my collection would a string inputted by the user

```
db.$$<VarCollectionName>.insertOne({........]);
```

Doing this causes my program to crash. What is the correct syntax to go about doing this? The end goal is to create a new collection everytime the user uses my method and parse a text file into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To insert in node into a Mongo Collection the command is:
>   `db.collection.insertOne({.........});`

It's not, actually, at least not when you're using the official driver, where the syntax [would be](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Db.html#collection):

```
db.collection(NAME).insertOne(...);
```

So `NAME` can be a user-provided variable (although from a security standpoint, you should probably validate if the user is allowed to write to that collection).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to MongoDB, just the [usual JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

```
db[variableHoldingTheCollectionName].insertOne({...});
```